# Setuptools with entry_points

Tags: python, installation, setuptools

I would like to install a script with setuptools and have the following setup:

In my development directory there are the files

- setup.py and
- z_script.py.

The `z_script.py` file looks like this:

```
def main():
    print "Running..."
```

while my `setup.py` looks like this:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
      name = 'z_script', version = '0.2', 
      entry_points = {"console_scripts": ["z_script = z_script:main"]},
      )
```

When I run `python setup.py install` the script successfully gets installed into the correct `bin` directory.

However, when I run the script with `z_script` an error occurs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./z_script", line 8, in <module>
    load_entry_point('z-script==0.2', 'console_scripts', 'z_script')()
  File "/home/woltan/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 318, in load_entry_point
  File "/home/woltan/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 2221, in load_entry_point
  File "/home/woltan/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 1954, in load
ImportError: No module named z_script
```

The `bin` directory is accessible through the `PATH` environment variable from thought the system and no `PYTHONPATH` environment variable is set when I issue the `z_scirpt`.

And now to my question:

What is wrong in my setup? Why isn't the script finding the correct module?

Comment: "However, when I run the script with z_script"?  Please include the actual code.  Almost universally your `PATH` has the local directory first and installed bin directories later.  You should probably CD to any other directory on the machine to see if the installation worked.  Please include `PATH` and `PYTHONPATH` environment variables, also.

Comment: @S.Lott `z_script` is successfully installed in the path `~/local/bin` which is available in `PATH` environment variable. So I can execute it from anywhere on my machine. And I already posted all the actual code there is...

Comment: @S.Lott The command is `z_script` which I can run from anywhere on my machine because it is accessible through the `PATH` environment variable. I don't have any `PYTHONPATH` variable set when I run the script.

Comment: Please **update** the question with the details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't instruct setuptools to install the `z_script`. Use [`find_packages`](http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/setuptools#using-find-packages) or list `z_script` in the `py_modules` keyword.

```
...
packages = find_packages(),
...
```

or

```
...
py_modules = ['z_script'],
...
```